# $L^{2}$ norm and expected value.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a random variable such that takes values on a functional space of type $L^{2}$ ($L^{2}(I)$, that is, $L^{2}$ functions $f: I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $I$ a compact of $R^{p}$). Let $f,g\in L^{2}(I)$. My question is if
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}[\|X - f\|_{L^{2}}]\geq\|f - g\|_{L_{2}}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}[\|X - g\|_{L^{2}}]\geq\|f - g\|_{L_{2}}
\end{equation}
is true. It can be expressed also as
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\max\{\text{E}[\|X - f\|_{L^{2}}, \text{E}[\|X - g\|_{L^{2}}\}\geq\|f - g\|_{L^{2}}.
\end{equation}

Thans in advance.

Comment: What is the distribution of $X$?

Comment: If it is possible without hypothesis about the distribution

Comment: What would expectation mean without a distribution???

Comment: I mean, every continuous distribution. It doesn't matter what distribution is

Comment: If $g$ is arbitrary, then the right hand side is arbitrarily large, it is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is true with a constant $2$.
$$
\begin{align*}
\|f-g\|_{L^2} = \mathbb{E}_X(\|f-g\|_{L^2}) &≤ \mathbb{E}_X(\|f-X\|_{L^2} + \|X-g\|_{L^2})
\\
&\leq \mathbb{E}_X(\|f-X\|_{L^2}) + \mathbb{E}_X(\|X-g\|_{L^2})
\\
&\leq 2\max\left(\mathbb{E}_X(\|f-X\|_{L^2}),\mathbb{E}_X(\|X-g\|_{L^2})\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Is this sufficient for you?

Comment: In fact, this constant cannot be improved. Let $Y \sim \mathrm{Ber}(1/2)$ and set $X = Y f + (1-Y) g$ (so that $X=f$ and $X=g$ each with probability $1/2$). Then $\Bbb{E}[\|X-f\|] = \frac{1}{2}\|f-g\|$, and similarly $\Bbb{E}[\|X-g\|] = \frac{1}{2}\|f-g\|$.

Comment: Great, thank you for this example!